# React POST Methods returns empty array instead of object

Tags: reactjs, post, get

Hello Stack Community,

I have a situation where I would require your experience and view. I am trying to solve this for 2 days now and I cannot get it done.

When I'm trying to add a new object (called subscription), the post method returns and empty array instead of an object.
I use MongoDB.
Here are the code snippets:

Subscription schema:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const subscriptionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  monthlyPrice: { type: Number, default: 0, required: true },
  yearlyPrice: {type: Number, default: 0, required: true},
  copyType: { type: String, required: true},
  seoType: { type: String, required: true},
  personalizationType: { type: String, required: true},
});

const subscriptionModel = mongoose.model('Subscription', subscriptionSchema);

export default subscriptionModel;
```

Subscription Route:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const subscriptions = await Subscription.find({});
  res.send(subscriptions);
});

router.post('/', isAuth, isAdmin, async (req, res) => {
  const subscription = new Subscription({
    name: req.body.name,
    monthlyPrice: req.body.monthlyPrice,
    yearlyPrice: req.body.yearlyPrice,
    copyType: req.body.copyType,
    seoType: req.body.seoType,
    personalizationType: req.body.personalizationType
  });
  const newSubscription = await subscription.save();
  if (newSubscription) {
    return res
    .status(201)
    .send({ message: 'New Subscription created', data: newSubscription });
  }
  return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error on creating a new subscription'});
})
```

Subscription Actions:

```
const saveSubscription = (subscription) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: SUBSCRIPTION_SAVE_REQUEST, payload: subscription });
    const { userSignIn: { userInfo }} = getState();
    if(!subscription._id) {
      const { data } = await Axios.get('/api/subscriptions', subscription, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + userInfo.token,
        },
    });
    dispatch({ type: SUBSCRIPTION_SAVE_SUCCESS, payload: data})
    } else {
      const { data } = await Axios.put('/api/subscriptions/' + subscription._id, subscription, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + userInfo.token,
        },
      });
      dispatch({ type: SUBSCRIPTION_SAVE_SUCCESS, payload: data});
    }
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: SUBSCRIPTION_SAVE_FAIL, payload: error.message});
  }
}
```

Subscription reducer:

```
function subscriptionSaveReducer(state = { subscription: {} }, action ) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SUBSCRIPTION_SAVE_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true };
    case SUBSCRIPTION_SAVE_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, subscription: action.payload, success: true };
    case SUBSCRIPTION_SAVE_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

If you can help, please have a look and help me with a solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

router.post('/', isAuth, isAdmin, async (req, res)

In this particular line try to put post in all caps like "POST"... That should work.
If such lines are there anywhere else make sure to put post in all caps.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for answering. Unfortunately, the solution proposed by you doesn't work. Router doesn't recognize.